# Account Kit advanced UI customizing

Tags: android, account-kit

My default color is purple (`#9b59b6`) i want to change top title (blue) color to purple as well. I red manual on [Customizing the Account Kit UI in Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/android/customizing) Implemented style like this, but had no further luck changing top title color to purple.

```
//Delauft color: purple
UIManager uiManager = new SkinManager(SkinManager.Skin.CONTEMPORARY, ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.default_color), R.drawable.register_screen, SkinManager.Tint.WHITE, 0.1);
configurationBuilder.setUIManager(uiManager);
```

In my `style.xml` i have

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#9b59b6</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#9b59b6</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#9b59b6</item>
    <!-- other elements-->
</style>
```

Other activities works fine.

I have app that look like this:

[image]

**UPDATE**

Solution: In `AndroidManifest`

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.accountkit.ui.AccountKitActivity" android:theme="@style/CustomFbStyle" tools:replace="android:theme"/>
```

And in style.xml

```
<style name="CustomFbStyle" parent="Theme.AccountKit">
<item name="colorPrimary">#9b59b6</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">#9b59b6</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the theme you are using i.e Appbasetheme is the same which you have mentioned in application tag of manifest.

```
  <application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppbaseTheme">
```

or you can also use specific theme to specific class by giving android:theme tag to that class in manifest

Comment: Manifest file has android:theme="@style/AppTheme" but in my style there is   <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme"></style> in order to support older android API versions. AS i said In other activities everything is okey. Problem is with Facebook account kit.

Comment: Try one thing you have mention Facebookactivityclass in manifest i.e inbuild class use android:theme="@style/AppbaseTheme"

Comment: With a bit of Digging i succeed. first i used android:theme="@style/CustomFbStyle" tools:replace="android:theme" and in style.xml `<style name="CustomFbStyle" parent="Theme.AccountKit">
        <!--<item name="android:background">#fff</item>-->
        <item name="android:textColor">#9b59b6</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">#9b59b6</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#9b59b6</item>
    </style>`
 Please update your answer and i will mark it as correct one. Thanks.